# Where from 2 conditions in SQL Server & C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I write this code? I get an error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.

Code:

```
SqlCommand command =new SqlCommand("select * from inventory WHERE barcode1 and barcode2= '" + textBox10.Text + "'", con);

SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

con.open();

while (read.Read())
{
    textBox4.Text = (read["parts"].ToString());
}

read.close();
```

Comment: You have to compare barcode1 to something like you did for bardcode2. Secondly use parametrized query to avoid SQL injection. Lastly you still need to execute the command to get the records you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE barcode1 and barcode2=
```

Where `barcode1` *what*?  You have to finish the expression before beginning the next expression.  Maybe something like this?:

```
WHERE barcode1 = @barcode1 AND barcode2 = @barcode2
```

(Note also the use of query parameters instead of directly concatenating user input.  This would help prevent SQL injection attacks, to which your current code is highly vulnerable.)

---

You can, of course, use the same value for the different parameters.  So something like this:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE barcode1 = @barcode1 AND barcode2 = @barcode2", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode1", textBox10.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode2", textBox10.Text);
// now you can execute the query
```

Answer (score 0):

Man Doesnt Work...Works only if i will choose one barcode

```
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE barcode1 = @barcode1", con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode1", textBox10.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode2", textBox10.Text);
```